# How can I convert logs to odds ratio and logs to probabilities for logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, glm, survey

*From here: [R: Calculate and interpret odds ratio in logistic regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384075/r-calculate-and-interpret-odds-ratio-in-logistic-regression)*

After running logistic regression model with glm with logit link to convert logits to odds ratio, you can exponentiate it:

```
exp(coef(m))
```

To convert logits to probabilities, you can use the function:

```
exp(m)/(1+exp(m))
```

**Question:** How to do the same with quasibinomial regression with log (`family=quasibinomial(log)`) and quasipoison regression (`family=quasipoisson("log")`)? How can I convert logs to odds ratio and logs to probabilities if I use log link?

*I am using survey package for R (for most of regression calculations it uses glm).*

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? Or perhaps a model specification? With a log link, your response isn't bounded to be between 0 and 1, so I don't see how probabilities or odds ratios apply... (Also, this doesn't seem to be a programming question, so if you can refine it to be clearer, it should be moved to stats.stackexchange)

Comment: But if you look at `?family`, the allowed link functions for binomial data (where odds ratios and probabilities would make sense) are `logit`, `probit`, and `cauchit`. `log` link with a `binomial` family GLM doesn't exist AFAIK.

Comment: @Gregor You are right. Thank you. I use survey package for R (for most of regression calculations it uses glm). I tried to simplify question and thought that glm had same calculations available as survey package. I updated my question.

Comment: With a quasipoisson regression, you're modeling counts, not probabilities, so I still think your off base. [This answer on stats.stackexchange talks about interpreting quasipoisson coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/385864/7515).

Comment: I don't see how the `survey` package is relevant. The `quasibinomial` family is documented at the same `?family` page referenced above--it doesn't look like the survey package changes anything about that. The default link for `quasibinomial` is `"logit"`. R will let you set a `log` link, but I don't think it makes any sense. In a quick google search, I couldn't find any examples of people using a quasibinomial family with a log link---I would advise you to not do it either.

Comment: I won't be replying to more comments on this question on Stack Overflow. It's certainly a statistical question, not a programming question. If you want more help understanding this issue, I strongly suggest moving the question to stats.stackexchange.