# Logistic Regression Odds Ratio unusual value in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set with response variable `COVID.Vaccines` and I want to perform logistic regression with `Gender` as an explanatory variable. The script I have is designed to find the odds ratio, 95% CI of it, and p-value for each level (Male and Female):

```
# Fit logistic regression model
my_data$Gender <- relevel(my_data$Gender, ref = "Male")
model <- glm(COVID.Vaccines ~ Gender, data = my_data, family = "binomial")

# Get coefficients
coefficients <- coef(model)

# Get standard errors
standard_errors <- summary(model)$coefficients[, "Std. Error"]

# Calculate odds ratios
odds_ratios <- exp(coefficients)

# Calculate lower and upper confidence intervals
lower_ci <- exp(coefficients - 1.96 * standard_errors)
upper_ci <- exp(coefficients + 1.96 * standard_errors)

# Combine results into a data frame
results <- data.frame(
  Expl_Var = names(coefficients),
  Odds_Ratio = odds_ratios,
  CI = paste0(round(lower_ci, 3), "-", round(upper_ci, 3)),
  P_Value = summary(model)$coefficients[, "Pr(>|z|)"]
)

# Print results
print(results)
```

I consistently get an Odds Ratio of 3 for Male, which doesn't make sense, because the odds ratio should be compared to itself (in other words, it should equal 1). Is there something wrong with my script?

Have tried forcing the reference to be Male, but I get unusual ORs no matter which is the reference

Comment: Hi! A reproducible example would be nice. Also check here, maybe that does answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384075/r-calculate-and-interpret-odds-ratio-in-logistic-regression?rq=2

Comment: Welcome to SO, Boppy2! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a great start here!); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.